# SQL Count from Sub Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to count some columns from sub table. My table structure is below:

**Persons**

```
+---+----------+--------+
| Pid | Name   |Surname |
+---+----------+--------+
| 1   | Per A  | D      |
| 2   | Per B  | E      |
| 3   | Per C  | F      
+----+---------+--------+
```

**Childs**

```
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+
| Cid | CName          | School   | Sex        | Pid |
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+
| 1   | John           | High     |    Man     | 1   |
| 2   | Alice          | Primary  |    Woman   | 2   |
| 3   | Mel            | High     |    Man     | 3   |
| 4   | Angelina       | High     |    Woman   | 2   |
+----+---------+------------------+------------+-----+
```

**So I want to output**

```
+---+----------+------+---------+--------+---+--------------+
| Pid| PerName | High | Primary | Woman  | Man | ChildCount | 
+---+----------+------+---------+--------+-----+------------+
| 1  | Per A   | 1    | 0       | 0      | 1   | 1          |
| 2  | Per B   | 1    | 1       | 2      | 0   | 2          |
| 3  | Per C   | 1    | 0       | 0      | 1   | 1          |
+----+---------+------+---------+--------+-----+------------+
```

**How can I get this output?**

I try this method but i have more columns like this to calculate belongs to Child table. So I get slow query results.

```
select Pid,Name,Surname,
  (select count(*) from Childs where Persons.Pid=Childs.Pid) ChildCount, 
  (select count(*) from Childs where Persons.Pid=Childs.Pid and School='Primary') Primary 
from Persons
```

Comment: JOIN the tables. Do a GROUP BY.

Comment: I want to Group By with Pid only but SQL want other columns also like Name, Surname etc. If in mysql no problem but in mssql problem

Comment: Newer MySQL versions wont let you do that invalid GROUP BY - unless in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select p.Pid, p.Name,
       sum(case when c.school = 'High' then 1 else 0 end) as high,
       sum(case when c.school = 'Primary' then 1 else 0 end) as primary,
       sum(case when c.sex = 'Man' then 1 else 0 end) as Man,
       sum(case when c.sex = 'Woman' then 1 else 0 end) as Woman,
       count(*) as ChildCount
from persons p left join
     childs c
     on p.pid = c.pid
group by p.Pid, p.Name;
```

Comment: I want to Group By with Pid only and want to select Name, Surname also but SQL want other columns also like Name, Surname etc. Because of same Name. How can we do that

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
select Pid,Name,Surname,
ifNull((select count(*) from Childs where Persons.Pid=Childs.Pid),0) ChildCount,
ifNull((select count(*) from Childs where Persons.Pid=Childs.Pid AND School='High' GROUP By Childs.Pid),0) High,
ifNull((select count(*) from Childs where Persons.Pid=Childs.Pid AND School='Primary' GROUP By Childs.Pid),0) 'primary',
ifNull((select count(*) from Childs where Persons.Pid=Childs.Pid AND Sex='Woman' GROUP By Childs.Pid),0) Woman,
ifNull((select count(*) from Childs where Persons.Pid=Childs.Pid AND Sex='Man' GROUP By Childs.Pid),0) Man

from Persons;
```